# Facebook code to prompt for stream publish with in application

Tags: facebook

I have a bit confusion using facebook API. I am using a code that is working out side of facebook but not in facebook application canvas page.

I have bit idea but not sure. Can anybody let me know the reason behind this and the code that will run in facebook application.

What is difference you run code using application like

```
http://apps.facebook.com/exampleAPP/test.php
```

or normal url

```
http://www. example.com/example/test.php
```

`http://www. example.com/example/` is the canvas URL

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '115454544334343454',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });


  FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    attachment: {
      name: 'JSSDK',
      caption: 'The Facebook JavaScript SDK',
      description: (
        'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
        'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
        'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
      ),
      href: 'http://fbrell.com/'
    },
    action_links: [
      { text: 'fbrell', href: 'http://fbrell.com/' }
    ]
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure `stream.publish` is deprecated and unsupported. What you want instead is the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).